# deployment of persistence unit failed issue

Tags: java

wHEN I AM DEPLOYING MY CRUDWEB web application it is throwing like below:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [CRUBWEB] : Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [CRUBWEBPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT e FROM custt e]. 
[14, 19] The abstract schema type 'custt' is unknown.
```

Please help Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that you have not created the required database schemas.

Comment: I have Database table custt created under authenticate DB in mysql

Comment: What is the schema for the custt table?

Comment: custt(cid(PK,auto generation,cname varchar,accno(FK),bal)